# Ruby on Rails - Simple form client side validation that response was entered before submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, forms

I am trying to do a very simple validtion on a form with only radio buttons  to check that a user selected an option on the question before submitting the page. Is there a simple way to do this in my view other than relying on jquery validation or doing the validation in the model?

Mariam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your own validation function and call it on form submit event, the function checks the radio button and should return true or false based on condition.

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">

<input type="radio" name="radio_param" value="val  1" />
<input type="radio" name="radio_param" value="val  2" />
<input type="radio" name="radio_param" value="val  3" />
</form>

<script>
function validateForm(f){

var radioButtons = f.radio_param;
var selected = false;
for(var i = 0;i< radioButtons.length;i++){
 selected = radioButtons[i].checked;
 }
if(!selected)
 alert("no option selected");
return selected ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way to suppress my controller action when no option is selected?                                        in the code below, I want to forward to the controller only when a value is added. Right now the controller is invoked whether or not an option was selected. <% form_tag ({:controller => "posts", :action => "test"}, :onSubmit => "validate_form(this)") do %>

Comment: why do you want to suppress your action? yes, you can do it but there could be other ways to solve your problem so mention your requirement why do you want it.

Comment: Thanks Naren. Actually I needed to do "return validate_form(this)"... I forgot the "return". But I think in general I am not following best practices here. I am just showing a simple question with radio button options on this form and if the user doesn't answer it, I want to stay on that page and not move to the next question (which is what the controller does -- it forwards to the next question).

Comment: ok, if this satisfy your question then please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do client side validation, you need javascript to handle this, plain and simple. You don't have to do rely on jQuery but it does provide some validation niceties.